# Making a calculator that does operation of x number of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, console, println

```
package com.company;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class ENCRYPTED {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        //Declaring scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Declaring Arrays
        double[] numbers = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,};
        String[] op = {"+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+",};
        double[] ans = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,};

        //Getting Number of Numbers
        System.out.println(" How many numbers to add/subtract ? : ");
        int nofns = sc.nextInt();

        // for loop that executes to get the numbers
        for (int i = 0; i < nofns; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter Number " + i + " : ");
            numbers[i] = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter Operator for number " + i + " : ");
            op[i] = sc.next();
            ans[i] = numbers[i] + numbers[i+1];
            System.out.println(ans[i]);
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);
            System.out.println(op[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

this is a program I made that takes in x numbers of numbers and stores them in the array (numbers) and operators (op). I want to store the operations done (-,+,*,/) on the ans array. I want to get a logic for this program that does the operations and stores them in the array. so these are my question.

1. How do I write this
   Write this : (This taken from numbers array:5) ((This taken from op array)-) (This taken from numbers array:4) = (Stored and printed in ans aray)1

thanks for all for reading this

EDIT: "I just discovered the method for adding and substracting but I still want to find the multiplication and division, Sorry for not commenting the code"

THIS IS THE IMPROVED CODE

```
package com.company;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class ENCRYPTED {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        //Declaring scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Declaring Arrays
        double[] numbers = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,};
        String[] op = {"+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+","+",};
        double[] ans = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,};
        double sum=0;

        //Getting Number of Numbers
        System.out.println(" How many numbers to add/subtract ? : ");
        int nofns = sc.nextInt();

        // for loop that executes to get the numbers
        for (int i = 0; i < nofns; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter Number " + i + " : ");
            numbers[i] = sc.nextDouble();   //Ex : 5
//            System.out.println("Enter Operator for number " + i + " : ");
//            op[i] = sc.next(); //Ex: +
            System.out.println("Enter Number " + i + " : ");
            numbers[i+1] = sc.nextDouble();   //Ex : 6
            ans[i] = numbers[i] + numbers[i+1];
            System.out.println("Answer is " + ans[i]);
            if (i == nofns) {
                break;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<nofns; i++){
            sum = sum + ans[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Elements of the sums are: "+Arrays.toString(ans));
        System.out.println("Sum of the numbers :: "+sum);

    }
}
```

IF anyone can suggest the method for multiplication and division, thanks for the help
"OUTPUT:
Number one  : 4
Number Two : -2
and : 2"
NOTE: YOU NEED TO SUFFIX "-" SIGN BEFORE THE NUMBER TO SUBSTRACT IT

Answer (score 1):

This looks like homework so I'll go at a high level. In general, you want to handle each of the 4 cases you have. Those cases are (+-*/) and maybe teh default case where you have invalid input. Then, based on what the value of `op[i]` you will perform the corresponding item instead of unconditionally adding like this: `ans[i] = numbers[i] + numbers[i+1];`

Comment: I didn't understand that. I am doing that but keeps giving ans as zero. at this point I am really stuck and really need help